# Can display apps damage AMOLED screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I used app Screen Balance (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.quickdoc.screenbalance&hl=sl) and one other screen app on my Galaxy S7 Edge and later (weeks or months later) I got some pink line and always on pixels. Is possible that this happened because of this apps? I like this apps because they can make colors on Galaxy S7 Edge display better (more cold) than original. Now I have new display on my phone and I am wondering if it is ok that I use Screen Balance and another screen app.

Thank you.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Amoled screens can burn up. In bright colored UI, but for your case screen balance only adds some screen warmth (red hues) and coldness (blue hues) on it not changing the entire UI color like pure black or pure light. I don't think that can be a reason to your spoiling of screen. That is a totally different reason it got burning pixels.